# C++ global structure creates name conflict

Tags: c++, conflict, naming

I have written a quite extensive framework that drives characters in a physical simulation. Even though everybody warned me not to do it, I used a global public data structure for storage of information and called it State. It's not in a namespace either. I make it globally accessible by declaring extern State state;. The reason why I did this is because this structure is needed everywhere in the application and I find it extremely convenient to just include my State.h and then write to state.var anywhere and read state.var anywhere. The framework is changing rapidly, too, and I also find comfort in not having to care about passing data around, synchronizing etc. when new components are introduced.

Anyhow, now the s*** hit the fan. I want to use one of Qt's GUI classes and it already has it's own member called state of type State. Their state is at least in a namespace, but it doesn't seem to matter, since inside the class I'm already using that namespace.

What can I do now?

Comment: Was/is there a reason not to use namespaces? Because the exactly what theyre here for. Preventing name clashes without forcing you to use classes

Comment: No there is no reason other than my inexperience and not seeing a need to do so. But I figure, even if I did put my State in a namespace, the global variable name state would still conflict with the GUI class' state.

Comment: @Marcell your global variable would also be in the namespace. Wouldn't that resolve the conflict?

Comment: If you qualify it on every occurence, like `mynamespace::State` there shouldnt be a problem :-) Instead of `using namespace`

Comment: @Marcell, got to agree, I think your understanding of namespaces is incomplete. Of course there will be a conflict if you say `using namespace xxx;` or `using xxx::State;`. So don't do that, qualify each use of State with it's namespace. Or you could just rename your State class to something a bit more app specific.

Comment: juanchopanza -> Yes, that's a good suggestion. I will need to qualify each occurence of the global state variable to namespace::state, but I guess that's an acceptable price. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I probably do not understand the problem, but what's stopping you from doing

```
::state.var
```

?

Plain `::` means global namespace, and while using global symbols has the well known issues, and global variables also have their own set of issues (generally in C++ code, singletons are used instead), there's nothing magically evil about using a global variable in the global namespace. `::errno` is an example of such a variable linked to practically every C and C++ application on Unix-like platforms.

Comment: Excellent solution, thank you! The thing stopping me from it was that I didn't know about the global qualifier ::. This works great and I don't have to change anything.

Answer (score 6):

Your only choice is to rip out your global and replace it with something sane. This is extremely painful but you really don't have any other option. This is why people recommended against using one in the first place.

In short, congratulations on learning the lesson at hand- don't use global variables.

Comment: Yes, this is what everyone is suggesting, but then again no one is offering a painless alternative to solve the issues I stated above, namely the high grade of information flow between components and the rapid change of components.

Comment: @Marcell I understand you...it would be a lot of work/pain to get rid of the global State. But it may be worth it in the long run. Otherwise use namespaces, it's the least painful way I  can think of

Comment: @Marcell - there is no painless alternative. You're twenty miles from civilization, your car has broken down, and your cellphone doesn't work. You have to walk back.

Comment: I disagree, Pete. I can try to find a way to fix it and continue down this road. I don't care if other people call it a desert, it's very easy to walk.

Comment: Evegni: I'm not worried about the effort to change the structure. The single thing I'm focused on is using the framework and maintaining the freedom to try out things very quickly, which i solved best by using the global structure in my humble opinion.

Comment: The painless route is called "Design it properly". Everybody else designs their app, then they write it, and they simply pay the price required to have well-structured code. There is no solution to this problem. If you can find one, you'll be a millionaire within a week. You might as well complain that I'm not offering a solution to an NP-Complete problem that runs in P time.

Comment: "Design it properly" is the most useless and unconstructive answer to every architectural issue out there. Especially if you don't even consider the use case and why it might have lead to design decision being made a certain way.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a simple alternative:

```
extern State state;
State& mystate = state;

namespace qt {
    class State;

    class Gui {
    public:
        void foo() {
            mystate.var = 3;
        }

    private:
        State* state;
    };
}
```

... but there is also something called [Technical Debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt), and you are borrowing deeply.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what I would be borrowing?

Comment: @Marcell: it was a playword on "Technical Debt" ;) Did you read the article ? Here, you are only digging a deeper and deeper grave (or piling sh*t higher and higher, to use your words). At one point you *will have* do something about it. Therefore, postponing the inevitable feels like borrowing money: it might allow you to do something *now* that you could not otherwise, but at some point you will have to clean up your slate, with interests.

Comment: I read the article. But I'm still not seeing what grave I'm digging, to use your words. :) Why will I ever have to do something about "it"?

Comment: Just saying, over ten years later now, my state object is still thriving and doing a great job at its purpose of being a publicly available data exchange buffer. No problems occurred with it ever again.